# COUNT() function NOT returning the number of rows that matches a specified criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compute the number of bicycles sold by state for 2009. This is from the RollingThunder database. Here is my code:

```
SELECT
  Bicycle.OrderDate,
  States.StateName
FROM
  Bicycle,
  States
WHERE
  Bicycle.OrderDate = '2009'

SELECT COUNT(Bicycle.OrderDate) FROM Bicycle;
```

However, my result is a long list, which is not giving me a number of bicycles. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing at some of the column names here (and it seems odd that Orders are in a table called Bicycle), but it would be something like:

```
SELECT
  States.StateName,
  Count(1) AS Cnt
FROM Bicycle
LEFT JOIN States
ON Bicycle.StateCode = States.StateCode
WHERE Year(Bicycle.OrderDate) = 2009
GROUP BY States.StateName
ORDER BY States.StateName
```

Comment: I got an error saying "Invalid column name 'StateCode'.

Comment: @CABurns Yes, I don't know what your columns are really named. The approach is to join to the state table and to group by the state name and do a count.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code should look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Bicycle.OrderDate) FROM Bicycle WHERE Bicycle.OrderDate = '2009' GROUP BY Bicycle.OrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you want as the final output is the number of bicycles sold in each state, in 2009.

Try this(Assuming the OrderDate is of DATE type),

```
SELECT DISTINCT(S.StateName),COUNT(B.OrderDate)
FROM Bicycle B,States S 
WHERE B.OrderDate>='2009/01/01' and B.OrderDate<='2009/12/31' and S.<columnName>=B.<columnName> 
GROUP BY S.StateName
```

*Note:* Specify the column name which joins the two tables, i.e the foreign key (`S.<columnName>=B.<columnName>`), Otherwise you will not get the desired output